# Save current post using custom save button

Tags: save-post, wp-redirect

I want to display a custom button in my "Edit post" screen which saves the current post (everything including custom fields) and then runs a function (in my case redirecting to another page).

I know how to redirect after saving the post using the `save_posts` action and `wp_redirect` but I can't figure out how to save the post when a custom button is clicked.

This is my function for redirecting using `save_post` (which doesn't work for me since I need to use a custom button):

```
function redirect_after_save_post() {
  global $post;

  if ( 'event' == get_post_type() ) {
    $url = 'http://www.google.com';
    wp_redirect( $url );
    exit;
  }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'redirect_after_save_post' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do. It doesn't create a new button, but will put a check mark right next to the publish/update button. The idea is that if you check the button before hitting the publish/update. It will run your function in the save. If it isn't check the system will save as normal. I have generalized the function names so you can make them more specific as well as button titles.

```
function rt_custom_save_action(){
    global $post;
    if (get_post_type($post) != 'post') //Choose Post type HERE
        return false;

        $html  = '<div id="major-publishing-actions" style="overflow:hidden">';
        $html .= '<div id="publishing-action">';
        $html .= '<label><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="custom_action" />SAVE WITH FUNCTION</label>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        echo $html;
}
add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'rt_custom_save_action' );

function rt_project_updated_save_dosomething( $post_id ) {
    

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
            return;
    // If this is just a revision, don't do anything.
    // if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
    //  return;

    // only go if user checked action checkbox.

    if(isset($_POST['custom_action'])){
        
    //PUT SOMETHING HERE THAT YOU WANT TO HAPPEN

    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'rt_project_updated_save_dosomething' ); //if you change the custom post type above, you have to change it here too (save_post_CUSTOMPOSTNAME)
```

If you wanted to use a button I suppose you could do this, I've removed the checkbox check in the function and added 2 button options. Try one then the other:

```
function rt_custom_save_action(){
    global $post;
    if (get_post_type($post) != 'post') //Choose Post type HERE
        return false;

        $html  = '<div id="major-publishing-actions" style="overflow:hidden">';
        $html .= '<div id="publishing-action">';
       // $html .= '<input type="submit" accesskey="p" tabindex="5" value="custom_action" class="button-primary" id="custom" name="custom_action" value="submitted">';
      // try this button code first.
      // $html .= '<button onclick="rt_project_updated_save_dosomething( $post_id );" accesskey="p" tabindex="5" class="button-primary" id="custom" name="custom_action">SEND WITH FUNCTION</button>';
      // try this one next but don't use both.
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        echo $html;
}
add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'rt_custom_save_action' );

function rt_project_updated_save_dosomething( $post_id ) {
    

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
            return;
    // If this is just a revision, don't do anything.
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;
        
    //PUT SOMETHING HERE THAT YOU WANT TO HAPPEN

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'rt_project_updated_save_dosomething' ); // If you change the custom post type above, you have to change it here too (save_post_CUSTOMPOSTNAME)
```

Comment: great answer! upvoted. However, strange problem here, if either custom_action button/input is placed anywhere other than [id="submitpost"] metabox then WordPress fires a JS dialog popup that warns "changes not saved, leave page?". Any ideas how to place the custom save button in some other metabox? for example: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/416201/wordpress-admin-panel-custom-submit-button-need-to-suppress-js-refresh-dialog

Answer (score -1):

I think you inject some code to display your custom button.

You can try to add the save post action in your code:

```
do_action('save_post');
```

And then add redirect code, be carefull with the Infinite loop.