# WordPress Admin panel: Custom submit button, need to suppress JS refresh dialog popup warning

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, metabox

## **Question:** Is it possible to remove the WP admin dialog popup when using a custom "publish" button?

**Consider this workflow:**

Custom post type that a special editor role [approver] will simply "approve or decline", the normal PUBLISH metabox will be hidden, a custom button will instead be used. The [approvers] can change some data on the CPT, such as the title. (all built, hooked and working fine)

[image]

**Creates this problem:**

If any of the content has changed (title, custom meta fields, tags, ect..) then when that custom button is clicked WP-admin Js layer prevents the action from taking place (because the normal 'publish' button was not clicked) and as such a JS dialog box popups up like so:

[image]

**This JS dialog popup is undesirable.** In the final system the default PUBLISH METABOX will be hidden and the custom metabox will instead guide the [approver] to take the correct actions.

Related WP threads. Note that the 'patches' proposed here do not work for Custom Post Types.

- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/52440
- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/52621
- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/52440#comment:52